# Laravel - Detectar si es null y no hacer update

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito actualizar información, pero hay archivos que no quiero que se actualicen como `$file_excel` o `$img_material` esta información a veces va vacía ya que vienen desde `input file`. ¿Cómo ignorar esto en el update si viene vacío?

```
$data = array(
            'area_envia' => $request->area_envia,
            'region' => $request->region,
            'territorio' => $inputs_string,
            'imagen_material' =>  $img_material == null ? null : $img_material,
            'nombre_material' => $request->nombre_material,
            'agregar_vigencia' => $request->agregar_vigencia,
            'excel' =>  $file_excel == null ? null :  $file_excel,
            'fecha_inicio_distribucion' => $request->fecha_inicio_distribucion,
            'fecha_maxima_llegada' => $request->fecha_maxima_llegada,
        );

        PopManager::find($request->get('id'))->update($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de abordar esto, lo que puedes hacer es removerlos del array si están vacíos, o incluso hacerlo desde el Request con el método except:

```
// $data = [ ... ];

if (is_null($file_excel)) {

    unset($data['excel']);

}

// actualizar información
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
$data = array(
            'area_envia' => $request->area_envia,
            'region' => $request->region,
            'territorio' => $inputs_string,
            'nombre_material' => $request->nombre_material,
            'agregar_vigencia' => $request->agregar_vigencia,
            'fecha_inicio_distribucion' => $request->fecha_inicio_distribucion,
            'fecha_maxima_llegada' => $request->fecha_maxima_llegada,
        );
 // validamos que no este vacio
 // si no lo esta lo asignamos al arreglo de datos y actualizamos
 // en caso contrario no hacemos nada y solo actualizara todo los otros

 if(!empty($img_material))
     $data['imagen_material'] =  $img_material;
 if(!empty($file_excel))
     $data['excel'] =  $file_excel;

PopManager::find($request->get('id'))->update($data);
```

Comment: Por favor explica un poco lo que hace el código, no es solo «puedes hacerlo así». Por cierto, tu respuesta no utiliza PSR-2, que es un estándar en Laravel y PHP.

Comment: culpa a la apk de stackoverflow por el formateo del codigo :v es practicamente imposible colocar los elementos donde gustas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes chequear primero y agregarlos al payload final sólo si son válidos:

```
$data = array(
    'area_envia' => $request->area_envia,
    'region' => $request->region,
    'territorio' => $inputs_string,
    'nombre_material' => $request->nombre_material,
    'agregar_vigencia' => $request->agregar_vigencia,
    'fecha_inicio_distribucion' => $request->fecha_inicio_distribucion,
    'fecha_maxima_llegada' => $request->fecha_maxima_llegada,
);

if(!is_null($img_material)) {
    $data['imagen_material'] = $img_material;
}
if(!is_null($file_excel)) {
    $data['excel'] = $file_excel;
}

PopManager::find($request->get('id'))->update($data);
```